# Why _vsnprintf crash at windows

Tags: printf

When will the _vsnprintf crash?

I use it like this:

```
   void My_Printf(const char *szFormatString, ...)
   {
      va_list my_args;
      va_start(my_args, szFormatString);
      AppendToLog(szFormatString, my_args);
      va_end(my_args);
    }

    static void AppendToLog(const char *szFormatString, va_list argptr)
    {
        char szLine[MAX_LENGTH_STRING] = {0};


      if ((NULL != szFormatString) && (0 != strcmp(szFormatString, ""))) {
        if (strlen(szFormatString) > MAX_LENGTH_STRING) {
          return;
        }

    #ifdef WIN32
       _vsnprintf(szLine, MAX_LENGTH_STRING-1, szFormatString, argptr);
    #endif
    ...
    }
```

and the VC show that it was broken at:

_VALIDATE_RETURN( (ch != _T('\0')), EINVAL, -1); (output.c)

I don't know why.

According to MSND, it should return a value whether it was ok or not.

Comment: Post your whole code, we're not psychic.  What are `szFormatString` and `argptr`?

Comment: First thing to check: does `szLine` actually pointer to a buffer of MAX_LENGTH_STRING characters?

Comment: And how did you create the va_list function parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is canonical code for using vsnprintf:

```
void Format( const char * fmt, ... ) {
  const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];
  va_list valist;
  va_start( valist, fmt );
  vsnprintf( &buf[0], BUFSIZE, fmt, valist );
  va_end( valist );
  // do something with buffer
}
```

Comment: it seems it was the same as my code, but the vsnprintf would be crash sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but keep in mind that vsnprintf (and _vsnprintf I guess since Microsoft says they're identical) return different values on Windows and Unix.  The Windows version returns -1 if you overflow the buffer, while the Unix version returns how many characters would have been written had the buffer been large enough.  Here's a couple of links that I found helpful in this regard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek(v=vs.80).aspx

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/590845-snprintf-return-value

EDIT: And here's an alternate version I found to get around this problem:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/75280/